# Grep not matching regular expression

Tags: regex, grep

I'm strugging a bit to get matching results from `grep`.

Given the following input file's contents

> {"foo":29, "bar":30}

and the following command `grep -o '"[^"]+":[0-9]+' input.txt`, I'm expecting two matching results. As far as I know it supports regular expressions, but I don't understand why `grep` doesn't return any results?

Other implementations of regexp are working fine (https://regex101.com/r/RcONXk/1).

Comment: Try adding `-E` to the grep command line.

Comment: `-E` seems to work, `-e` doesn't however. I think I have to read more about extended regexp :). Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: The `-e` simply takes the regex as the next argument.  It avoid problems when the regex might start with a dash, for example.  Or it allows you to have multiple regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this;

```
grep -oE '"[^"]+":[0-9]+'
```

Eg:

```
user@host:/tmp$ echo '{"foo":29, "bar":30}' | grep -oE '"[^"]+":[0-9]+'
"foo":29
"bar":30
```

man grep :

```
 -E, --extended-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```

[Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default, grep does not match regex. Either use the e flag:

```
grep -oe 'pat' file
```

Or use egrep (automatically treats pattern as regex).

```
egrep -o 'pat' file
```

Comment: This doesn't work (because of `-e`), but the other comment pointed me to `-E` which works.

Comment: -E is extended regex whereas -e is just regex.  My bad!

Comment: No problem, thanks for helping! :) `egrep` works too